# Открыть старую dll

Tags: c#, unity3d, dll

Есть старый ассет для Unity - последняя версия была для .NET 3.5
Ассет этот умеет рисовать текстуры на мешах, и делает это хорошо. Мне надо увеличить размер кисти - в оригинале он ограничен слайдером от 1 до 100, что делает невозможным рисование на больших объектах - кисть слишком маленькая. Я думал это поменять в скрипте, но, к сожалению, весь код вынесен в отдельную сборку .dll

Я попытался открыть .dll DotPeek и .NetReflector, и оно успешно открывается, я даже без проблем нахожу нужный класс и переменную - brush.size

Но что дальше? Кусок кода нужный мне выглядит примерно вот так

```
this.brush.size = GUI.Slider.value(0,100);
```

В идеале бы заменить его на

```
this.brush.size = GUI.Slider.value(0,10000);
```

и это бы скорее всего решило все мои проблемы. Но внутри самого DotPeek и Reflector ничего не меняется.
Как поменять одну строчку и сохранить dll обратно?

Если я выбираю экспорт проекта, он создает мне новый C# проект, внутри которого находятся и некоторые классы юнити, используемые этой сборкой, и классы самого ассета. И этот проект УЖЕ не компилируется, хотя только что был создан был декомпилером. Не находит часть типов, классов и ссылок на dll. Но как то он же жил без этого, находясь в сборке?

Возможно, я стреляю из пушки по воробьям и поменять строчку можно быстрее и проще - но как это сделать? Может быть это можно сделать прямо во время выполнения...

Comment: То, что декомпилированный проект не собирается  - это нормально. Если вы не знаете наверняка что исходники этой библиотеке не доступны в открытом виде, поищите ее на GitHub.

Comment: А нельзя ли сделать класс, унаследованный от дефолтного и там задать все нужные параметры? Переопределить методы, например и свойства и т.д. И в проекте использовать свой класс

Comment: Могу предложить ещё один способ решения задачи: использовать средства, которые изменяют код в рантайме на лету. Например, библиотеки [Harmony](https://harmony.pardeike.net/), [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose). Но въехать в них может оказаться не проще, чем добить сборку декомпилированного кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать dnSpy:
https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy

Загрузить сборку, найти нужный метод и, попробовать его поменять в редакторе кода и скомпилировать.

Если не получится, то есть вариант внести правки непосредственно в IL код, но это посложнее будет.

Не забудьте после исправлений сохранить модуль.

Comment: dnSpy отличная программа, я ею кривую игру патчил, чтобы пройти :D

Comment: Совершенно волшебная. Честно говоря, даже не знал про нее - спасибо автору за вопрос. Стало интересно как можно сам IL код править и нашёл её.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Будем использовать.